# jQuery- How to select a element with class name from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I am using jQuery.

I want to select a cell from a table. 
So I tried the following codes.

```
 // First line works fine for me. I can get a list of columns at the correct target row.
 var targetColumns = $(elemClicked).closest("tr").find("td"); 

 // I want to get the cell with the class named "draftstatus". This line has problem. I cannot get what I want.
 var targetCell = columnsAtTargetRow.$(".draftstatus");
```

The targetColumns inspected from browser looks like the following:
[image]

The 5th td above is my target cell.

I also try to use find() function. It won't work either because find() will start from next children level.

```
     columnsAtTargetRow.find(".draftstatus"); // this does not work.
```

What functions should I used to get that cell within that "list of td".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to read about [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: If you have the tds, try filter(".draftstatus") instead of find().

Comment: You could change find("td") to find("td.draftstatus") as well.

Comment: @abbottmw I tried find("td.draftstatus") before. it didn't work. I just tried filter(".draftstatus") and filter("td.draftstatus"), they do not work as well. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What does your html look like? Can you provide a watered down example?  Specifically of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to figure out which selectors to use.

```
var targetColumns = $(elemClicked).closest("tr").find("td");
```

this goes up the DOM to the "tr" and selects the tds.  If the **elemClicked** is inside a td you can select the tds with closest("td"), and then use siblings(".draftstatus");

If the elemClicked is a td, then you can just use siblings(".draftstatus");

Here is some example code to help demonstrate some selectors.  Hope this helps some and not confused you more.

```js
$(function(){
    
    
    //reference all cells with myclass class using filter
    $("#table1 tbody td").filter(".myclass").addClass("red");

    // click events for all tds reference the .target class cell using siblings
    $("#table1 tbody td").on("click",function(e){
        $(this).siblings(".target").toggleClass("red");
    }); 
    
  
  //items inside a table cell click event
    $("#table1 tbody td a").on("click",function(e){
      //toggle bold class
        $(this).closest("td").siblings(".target").toggleClass("bold");
          //prevent event from bubbling up 
          e.stopPropagation();
    }); 
})
```

```css
.red {
    background-color:red;
}

.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td class="myclass target">value2</td>
            <td>Two <a href="#">link</a></td>
        </tr>
      
       <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td class="myclass target">value2</td>
            <td>Two <a href="#">link</a></td>
        </tr>
      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
columnsAtTargetRow.$(".myclass");
```

This should be:

```
columnsAtTargetRow.find(".myclass");
```

Comment: I have tried this... it does not work. columnsAtTargetRow is a list of td elements. A list of td elements and that target cell has no parent-children relationship. So I think it makes sense that find() does not work here.